# How would I write the structure for this data in a Json file?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to include a Json file which holds data so I can pull it into my HTML file to use in creating a dynamic select option form.

For example if the first select option asks if you're a man or a woman, and lists man and woman as the choices, the next select option that is dynamically created would have choices specific to what you previously choice and those choices would be pulled from the Json file.

I want to be able to get that data if I say like

```
     Var data= new object();
     Data['male']=['tall', 'short'];
     data['tall']=['rich', 'poor'];
```

I think this structure is similar to associative arrays but I'm not too sure. So with the above lines, if the person chose male they would be given the options of tall or short, and if thy chose all they would be given the options of rich or poor.

I think the Json would be something like

```
  {"data": {

  man:[];
   woman:[];
  }

  }
```

If you could point me in the right direction of how to do this with an example, I would very much appreciate it, I don't have much experience writing Json myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, barring a couple of issues:

```
{
  "data": {
    "male": [
      "tall",
      "short"
    ],
    "tall": [
      "rich",
      "poor"
    ]
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that JSON should always use double quotes (`""`) for both keys and content.

Comment: Ahh, thank you, I had actually typed this out on my phone while waiting for my next class since I didn't have my laptop with me.

Comment: My question with what you've written is when I retrieve the data from my json file, would saying like data[0] give me the specific words "male" and allow me to display that in the option value or would it be returning what is inside of the "male" array? Also if I wanted to continue the branching for like "rich" would it just be "rich": [ "no hair", "hair" ] ? And thank you again for the help!

Comment: `data[0]` would return `undefined` - `data` is an object, so it doesn't know what to do with index values. `data["male"]` or `data.male` would return `["tall", "short"]`. `male` is an array, so `data.male[0]` would return `tall`. And yes, you can continue nesting objects and arrays as much as you want.

Comment: If you want to loop through the object to get keys, you can `for (var key in data) { console.log("Key: " + key); console.log("Value: " + data[key]); }`

Comment: Hmm, I see, well thank you so much for the help, you've certainly helped me understand this a bit better

Answer (score 1):

You can also declare an object in Javascript using the following syntax which is JSON:

```
var data = {
    'male': ['tall', 'short'],
    'tall': ['rich', 'poor']
};
```

Basically, you can declare a javascript object using `{}` instead of `new Object();` in which you can declare as many properties as you wish in this manner `"name": value`.

Properties in the object can be accessed in 2 ways: `data.male` or `data["male"]`.

Comment: Thanks, I know I can do it inside the html file, but for what I'm doing right now, I need to pull it in from another file.